# Vuejs how to add an item to an array from another array?

Tags: vue.js

i am making a product page and cart page, when i click on the Addtocart buton i want the product to be added to the cart page. Now i am wokring without a database so i just want to create an array of cart and when ever i click on the button the array is appended with that product

```
//this is product page
<template>
  <div class="container">
    //here i am listing the products
    <div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
      <div>
        <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1>
        //when i click this button i want to add the product the cart array, now to go to methods
        <button @click="Add" class="button" >Add to cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Product',
  data () {
    return {
      products: [
        {name: 'product1', description: 'preview text', id: '1'},
        {name: 'prduct2', description: 'preview text 2', id: '2'}
      ],
      cart: []
  },
  methods: {
    //when i click the button here i have no idea how to add the product the cart
    Add () {
      this.$set(this.cart, 'name', 'product1')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expect a param in the `Add` function which is the id of the product. Now you can get this id in the function and then fetch the product corresponding to this id and add it to the `cart` array.

Comment: You can simply add `{{cart}}` anywhere in your template to see its value for testing purpost. It will change as it is reactive.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Data
const data = {
  products: [
    {name: 'product1', description: 'preview text', id: '1'},
    {name: 'prduct2', description: 'preview text 2', id: '2'}
  ],
  cart: []
};

// Adding product '1' to cart
const id = '1'
data.cart.push( ...data.products.filter( item => item.id === id ) );

// Result
console.log( data );
```

Comment: Thank you! it works now, i have a litte question.
i passed the cart component that lists the cart array inside the product.vue component, <cart :cart="cart"/>
however i want to use this on separate page and not inside the product component page, how can i establish this ?

Comment: You have use Vuex. See this 10 minutes video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LW9yIR4GoVU

Answer (score 0):

In order to add something to the cart, you'll have to pass something that's unique for each and every product, like product id, to the Add function. And then using that information, you can append the cart list with your corresponding product. Sorry, I can't help you with the code 'cause i don't work  with vue.js, but I am pretty sure the above method would help. let me know if there is a problem